# Does FreeNX work with Nomachine Web Companion?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, java, nx, freenx

I have a working installation of the open source FreeNX, where I used [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) how to.

It mentions

> You can also embed your NX Server in a webpage by installing the
>   Nomachine Web Companion and the Apache webserver

Does that mean, that the java plugin [from](http://www.nomachine.com/download-companion.php) works with the open source FreeNX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works.  I have several machines set up with it.  You can pretty much just follow the Web Companion instructions.